# Chrome bug: skewed element looks pixelated

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, webkit

I have a block in the HTML (I use bootstrap) that is skewed, like this:

```
.skewed {
  -webkit-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
  transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
}
```

As I noticed, in Chrome it looks pixelated, so I added the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the `.skewed` class. Now the problem has gone - it is not pixelated anymore.

But then the other significant problem appeared: the text inside this block is blurred and ugly...

Take a look at the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt0nmkgt/), please.

Comment: I wonder if that's more of a contrast issue than simply Chrome's fault.  I played around with it, and even straightening it out still looked kinda sloppy.  Ick...  Even changing the font doesn't help.  Evidently Chrome has got a real problem rasterizing that text.

Comment: I remember reading a while ago something about adding a 1px transparent border to stop pixelation.

Comment: Thank you, Doug! I've tried to do so before, but it won't help. Also tried to add a white wide border (approx. 5px) - since I have a white background, I thought it will compensate the pixelation. But it did not :(

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe this help whoever see this by chance, to fix that problem just add backface-visibility: initial; to the end, see example

```css
.bar {
    background: red;
    color: #F5DDBB;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #aaa;
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
    transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0, -3.279deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: initial;
}

.bar .row {
     -webkit-transform: skew(0, 3.279deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(0, 3.279deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(0, 3.279deg);
    -o-transform: skew(0, 3.279deg);
    transform: skew(0, 3.279deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid bar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center">Welcome to the website</h2>
            <br/>
            <p class="text-center">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```